# reading a txt using C under linux. Where should I put the txt file?

Tags: c

I am trying to read from a txt file using C under Linux. 
    FILE*fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
I have the above code, but it's telling me "segmentation fault(core dumped)".
Is this because I don't have my txt under the correct directory?

```
int main(int argc, char*args[])
{
//printf("%d\n", argc);
int i;
for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
{
printf("%s ", args[i]);
}
int numProcesses=10;
int memorySize=atoi(args[1]);
int pageSize=atoi(args[2]);
int alloAlg=atoi(args[3]);
int evicAlg=atoi(args[4]);
int globLoc=atoi(args[5]);
int peroid=atoi(args[6]);

FILE*fp;
fp=fopen("Desktop/plist.txt","r");
char buff[1000];
//fgets(buff,100,fp);
//printf("%s",buff);
}
```

Comment: That line in itself won't cause a segmentation fault.  Post the rest of your code.

Comment: Just posted my code.  Don't know where went wrong...

Comment: You don't test whether the `fopen()` succeeded, so when it fails, you have a null pointer and it cause the code using the pointer to crash.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file without a path, it is assumed that file rests in the current directory. As for your segmentation fault -- you should be testing the `FILE` pointer against `NULL` before trying to read/write from it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Put your text file in the same folder where the executable is created.

Answer (score 0):

You are no getting segmentation fault because of `FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt","r")` command. (If this is what you are thinking)

If a file that you are trying to open by `fopen()` does not exist. `fopen()` will simply return NULL in that case.

You are getting segmentation fault, most probably, because you are trying to read something using the file pointer `fp`. For ex: you are doing something like `char ch = fgetc(fp)`.

To avoid this, you can always check the value returned by `fopen()`. NULL is return by `fopen()` if it cannot open the file.

So you could do something like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("text.txt","r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    //Your code to handle this case where file was not opened by fopen
}
else
{
    //Do what you wanted to do with your file
}
```

So, answer to your question is both yes and no.

Yes: because the segmentation fault is because fp contains NULL because your txt file is not in your directory.

No: because the segmentation fault is actually because you are trying to access memory that you are not supposed to (), and not because the txt file is not present in directory, however with a note that, the root cause for it is that your file was not present in the directory.

Comment: I think is because I'm using atoi. When I delete all the lines with atoi, it works fine. But I need to convert the command line input into integers. What should I do?

Comment: @user2817869: Check `argc` before accessing `args`: `if (argc < 7) { /* print error message and exit */ }`

Comment: @user2817869 To convert numeric strings to integers, you can use the fact that all integer characters have corresponding ASCII values. Characters 0-through-9 have ASCII values 48-through-57. If you dont want to try it yourself, you can google it, I am quite sure you will  find examples of it.